# Increase in app size after use of Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I tried using the Google Maps SDK for iOS and it seems to add a considerable amount of size (96MB) to our app, which is currently only at 26MB (using the Apple maps).

I would apprecaiate any feedback/experience on how to resolve.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a way to resolve this. Its one of the cons of working with Google Maps SDK vs Apple maps.

Google Maps SDK is its own static framework that isn't preloaded on the device. Apple Maps are build into the OS as a dynamic framework.

**Another Possibility:**
This is going to sound silly, but be sure you didn't copy the documentation or example code when downloading the Google Maps SDK into your app as well.

Comment: But 70 megs!?  Surely its not that large?

Comment: I'm sure it includes quite a few default images and its probably built  as a fat library to ensure it works with all devices and OS versions.

Comment: However this recent article mentions 6-8MB http://www.fastcolabs.com/3006725/open-company/depth-comparison-between-ios-map-frameworks-apple-mapkit-vs-google-maps-sdk so perhaps he is using an older version or one with a bunch of extra features such as offline support.

Comment: Any library that required as much as 70 megs would definitely not be worth bothering with for a mobile app ... so i doubt its even that its an older version ...

Comment: Any library that simply replicates built in functionality but leaves out key features and years worth of refactoring isn't worth bothering for :p

Comment: I updated my answer with another wild card possibility he may have accidentally overlooked.

Comment: The SDK should add 6-8MB to your app, if it is adding 70 meg then something has gone wrong with the way you included the SDK. Did you follow all the instructions correctly on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start?

Comment: You didn't include the framework to be compiled in did you?  That would explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Now with Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 1.3.1.3848 the SDK size is ONLY 15 MB while the previous version 1.3.0 was 157 MB. That's weird. I even downloaded it 3 times to make sure that this is the full file size. That's a big decrease in size from 157MB to just 15MB and there is nothing about it the release notes.

Comment: Three years after this answer, they have improved the SDK size on 2.0.0 version splitting the Places API from the Maps SDK resulting in a binary 70% smaller.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/releases#version_200_-_july_26_2016

Comment: @FormigaNinja hi I am a junior iOS developer, but when I install google map pod Only in my project, my project file is 133 mb ( I don't know if it is normal or not). but as far as I know, when the app is published to the app store, the size will be  smaller, could you please help me to give info about the estimation size of google map when it is published to the app store? I am using GoogleMaps (2.7.0). thanks in advance :)

Comment: @sarah Thank you for asking. Its a little off-thread here... so I suggest you to create it as a new question next time. But, answering you question, you can calculate the size of the app from Xcode like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620322/estimated-apps-store-size