# ios project folder size is much larger than size of all the files in it

Tags: ios

I found that my app new version is very large in size so I tried to clean some files in the project folder. The folder size is about 139 MB, but the size of the files inside it is only 49M. Screenshots are as follows. Is this normal? Because 139M is apparently too large for an app like mine, 49 would be acceptable.

[image: size of my project folder]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are comparing source code size to final app size?  That won't equate - since the app size includes the compiled code, libraries linked in, and your resources.  Are there large resource files you are potentially duplicating?

Comment: I am not sure, I have some frameworks added in my project, but why the folder is larger than files in it? Would the final app size affected by the folder size or the files size?

Comment: Folder size does not necessarily correlate to app size in any meaningful way, except for included resource files (eg. Images, video, audio).  Don't worry too much about the folder size, you need to worry about the generated archive size - e.g. The installable app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using git? Because git leaves a hidden directory, named `.git`, in your Project directory.

The size of your source directory has nothing to do with your final app size. You can't even estimate it that way.

You should archive your app and look at the size of the .app file. As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30620479/457406). That gives you an estimate.

Comment: I used ls -a and I found a .git file and a .DS_Store file. They are hidden and How can I show them and delete them?