# Impact of Xcode build options "Enable bitcode" Yes/No

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, bitcode

Yesterday I recognized a ton of warnings regarding the parse.com library:

> URGENT: all bitcode will be dropped because '[path]/Parse.framework/Parse(PFAnalytics.o)' was built without bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. Note: This will be an error in the future.

I am aware of the fact that I can remove those warning with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30856364/2442804) but am now wondering if it will have any negative impact in regards to AppStore submission and / or actual performance of my app.

Xcode informs you regarding bitcode

> Activating this setting indicates that the target or project should generate bitcode during compilation for platforms and architectures which support it.  For Archive builds, bitcode will be generated in the linked binary for submission to the app store.  For other builds, the compiler and linker will check whether the code complies with the requirements for bitcode generation, but will not generate actual bitcode. [ENABLE_BITCODE]

But I am not getting any really useful information out of this text.

- Can I use the linked answer to circumvent the issue without any negative impact and without compromising a future AppStore submission?
- What does the `ENABLE_BITCODE` actually do, will it be a non-optional requirement in the future?
- Are there any performance impacts if I enable / disable it?

Answer (score 481, accepted):

> - What does the ENABLE_BITCODE actually do, will it be a non-optional requirement in the future?

I'm not sure at what level you are looking for an answer at, so let's take a little trip. Some of this you may already know.

When you build your project, Xcode invokes `clang` for Objective-C targets and `swift`/`swiftc` for Swift targets. Both of these compilers compile the app to an [intermediate representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM#LLVM_Intermediate_Representation) (IR), one of these IRs is bitcode. From this IR, a program called LLVM takes over and creates the binaries needed for x86 32 and 64 bit modes (for the simulator) and arm6/arm7/arm7s/arm64 (for the device). Normally, all of these different binaries are lumped together in a single file called a [fat binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary#Apple.27s_Universal_binary).

The ENABLE_BITCODE option cuts out this final step. It creates a version of the app with an IR bitcode binary. This has a number of nice features, but one giant drawback: it can't run anywhere. In order to get an app with a bitcode binary to run, the bitcode needs to be recompiled (*maybe assembled or transcoded… I'm not sure of the correct verb*) into an x86 or ARM binary.

When a bitcode app is submitted to the App Store, Apple will do this final step and create the finished binaries.

Right now, bitcode apps are optional, but history has shown Apple turns optional things into requirements (like 64 bit support). This usually takes a few years, so third party developers (like Parse) have time to update.

> - can I use the above method without any negative impact and without compromising a future appstore submission?

Yes, you can turn off ENABLE_BITCODE and everything will work just like before. Until Apple makes bitcode apps a requirement for the App Store, you will be fine.

> - Are there any performance impacts if I enable / disable it?

There will never be negative performance impacts for enabling it, but internal distribution of an app for testing may get more complicated.

As for positive impacts… well that's complicated.

For distribution in the App Store, Apple will create separate versions of your app for each machine architecture (arm6/arm7/arm7s/arm64) instead of one app with a fat binary. This means the app installed on iOS devices will be smaller.

In addition, when bitcode is recompiled (*maybe assembled or transcoded… again, I'm not sure of the correct verb*), it is optimized. LLVM is always working on creating new a better optimizations. In theory, the App Store could recreate the separate version of the app in the App Store with each new release of LLVM, so your app could be re-optimized with the latest LLVM technology.

Comment: "Apple will create separate versions of your app for each machine architecture (arm6/arm7/arm7s/arm64) instead of one app with a fat binary. This means the app installed on iOS devices will be smaller." That is what Slicing does. This is unrelated to Bitcode.

Comment: "The ENABLE_BITCODE option cuts out this final step." It doesn't cut out any step. All the architecture binaries are still produced. PLUS bitcode information is then added for EACH architecture. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31030741/102008

Comment: @user102008 hmm… if that's the case maybe some of my information is out of date. From my reading, slicing is for bundles and bitcode is for binaries. Embedded FAT binaries would be needed for debug, ad-hoc, and enterprise apps. The FAT binaries could be discarded by Apple for app store apps during the submission process.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html "Slicing is the process of creating and delivering variants of the app bundle for different target devices. A variant contains only the **executable architecture** and resources that are needed for the target device."

Comment: @user102008 ["Apps you upload to iTunes Connect that contain bitcode will be compiled and linked on the App Store."](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html) So it seems like slicing does it one way and bitcode does it another. It's still a true statement about bitcode.

Comment: It is not a true statement that enabling Bitcode will make the app installed on the device smaller compared to when Bitcode is disabled. Nowhere does it say that.

Comment: "There will never be negative performance impacts for enabling it" is a bold claim. Perhaps it optimizes in such a way that it causes cache misses in a hot spot, or a branch prediction failure. Though it's unlikely to have anything but a positive effect on performance.

Comment: @JefferyThomas sorry, but why does 3rd library (Parse, Facebook, ...) have to update? What should they update? Isn't that Xcode does all the things for us?

Comment: @onmyway133 Not all vendors provide source. If all the vendor provides is a static lib and header files (or a Framework), then the vendor needs to have their stuff compiled with bitcode enabled.

Comment: I would like to add that if Enabled Bitcode is set to NO, you won't be able to build for Watch OS, which means if we have a watch app, we will have to adopt bitcode whatsoever :|

Comment: Bitcode is an intermediate representation of a compiled program. Apps you upload to iTunes Connect that contain bitcode will be compiled and linked on the store. Including bitcode will allow Apple to re-optimize your app binary in the future without the need to submit a new version of your app to the store.

https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH35-SW3

Comment: @JefferyThomas When submitting an app there's a "Include bitcode" checkbox. What's the difference with the ENABLE_BITCODE setting in my app's target? What if I have ENABLE_BITCODE false and keep that checkbox checked?

Comment: Very informative (and somewhat concerning) writeup here: https://medium.com/@FredericJacobs/why-i-m-not-enabling-bitcode-f35cd8fbfcc5#.gqwvu6av9

Comment: @allaire Good question. I'm not sure if this is the checkbox you are talking about, but there is a "Do not use bitcode auto-recompilation." checkbox under the "Pricing and Availability" section. It's getting kind of confusing, with all of these options, to know how they all work together (or not).

Comment: Your description is good, but leaves out several ill effects and complications. One - If I develop an app, and a Framework embedded in it, they BOTH must have the "enable bitcode" aligned, and If I turn on "deployment postprocessing" for my framework, in order to strip private symbols - all hell breaks loose, and I can't build. What is it REALLY doing?

Comment: @user102008 Bitcode is a pre-requisite of slicing. Unless until you enable the bitcode, Xcode won’t generate a bitcode binary and so the app store won’t be able to recompile it to generate smaller binaries and the slicing won’t happen.

Comment: @dev296: Slicing a fat binary does not require recompilation.

Comment: So can I get crash report using any third party library ? if I set bitcode NO.

Comment: XCode 14 Beta deprecates bitcode. It doesn't seem likely that apple will require bitcode for future apps.

Comment: XCode 15 Beta ignores ENABLE_BITCODE = YES completely. “Bitcode support has been removed, and the ENABLE_BITCODE build setting no longer has any effect. (105281961)”
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Xcode-Release-Notes/xcode-15-release-notes

Answer (score 72):

Make sure to select "All" to find the enable bitcode build settings:

[image: Build settings]

Comment: FINALLY A SCREENSHOT (also, why does submitting to Store not work unless bitcode is disabled..?)

Answer (score 36):

Bitcode is a new feature of [iOS 9](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html)

> Bitcode is an intermediate representation of a compiled program. Apps you upload to iTunes Connect that contain bitcode will be compiled and linked on the App Store. Including bitcode will allow Apple to re-optimize your app binary in the future without the need to submit a new version of your app to the store.
>
> Note: For iOS apps, bitcode is the default, but optional. If you provide bitcode, all apps and frameworks in the app bundle need to include bitcode. For watchOS apps, bitcode is required

So you should disabled bitcode until all the frameworks of your app have bitcode enabled.

Comment: 'Re-optimize your app binary in the future' - can you explain a little more?

Comment: Here it says that: "Bitcode is a new feature of iOS 9" and that "[...] For watchOS apps, bitcode is required [...]". So, what if I'd like to create a WatchOS app under iOS 8?

Answer (score 34):

**Bitcode makes crash reporting harder**. Here is a quote from [HockeyApp](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x/how-to-solve-symbolication-problems#bitcode) (which also true for *any other* crash reporting solutions):

> When uploading an app to the App Store and leaving the "Bitcode" checkbox enabled, Apple will use that Bitcode build and re-compile it on their end before distributing it to devices. This will result in the binary getting a new UUID and there is an option to download a corresponding dSYM through Xcode.

*Note: the answer was edited on Jan 2016 to reflect most recent changes*

Comment: Between Sep and Dec, this managed to get fixed via new Xcode Organizer export option (see the update in quoted HA howto) and broken again (see my solved [HA question](http://support.hockeyapp.net/discussions/problems/50477-symbolicating-bitcode-enabled-appstore-app-have-the-dsyms-downloaded))

Answer (score 21):

Bitcode is deprecated from XCode 14 Beta:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes

> Starting with Xcode 14, bitcode is no longer required for watchOS and tvOS applications, and the App Store no longer accepts bitcode submissions from Xcode 14.
>
> Xcode no longer builds bitcode by default and generates a warning message if a project explicitly enables bitcode: “Building with bitcode is deprecated. Please update your project and/or target settings to disable bitcode.” The capability to build with bitcode will be removed in a future Xcode release. IPAs that contain bitcode will have the bitcode stripped before being submitted to the App Store. Debug symbols for past bitcode submissions remain available for download. (86118779)

To anyone wondering about bitcode, it seems that it won't be necessary anymore.

Comment: But here it is still mentioned that Enabling bitcode will help in reducing app size.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/doing-basic-optimization-to-reduce-your-app-s-size

Comment: @VenkateshChejarla Not anymore! They managed to update the docs ;)

Comment: From the release notes of Xcode 15 beta: “Bitcode support has been removed, and the ENABLE_BITCODE build setting no longer has any effect. (105281961)”
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Xcode-Release-Notes/xcode-15-release-notes

Answer (score 14):

@vj9 thx. I update to xcode 7 . It show me the same error. Build well after set "NO"

[image]

set "NO" it works well.

[image]

Comment: @Septronic If you want to select YES. You need check your all third framework support this.

Comment: Your targets minimum supported iOS version has to be iOS 6 or higher.

Answer (score 6):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH35-SW2)

- can I use the above method without any negative impact and without compromising a future appstore submission?

Bitcode will allow apple to optimise the app without you having to submit another build. But, you can only enable this feature if all frameworks and apps in the app bundle have this feature enabled.
Having it helps, but not having it should not have any negative impact.

- What does the ENABLE_BITCODE actually do, will it be a non-optional requirement in the future?

> For iOS apps, bitcode is the default, but optional. If you provide
>   bitcode, all apps and frameworks in the app bundle need to include
>   bitcode. For watchOS apps, bitcode is required.

- Are there any performance impacts if I enable / disable it?

> The App Store and operating system optimize the installation of iOS
>   and watchOS apps by tailoring app delivery to the capabilities of the
>   user’s particular device, with minimal footprint. This optimization,
>   called app thinning, lets you create apps that use the most device
>   features, occupy minimum disk space, and accommodate future updates
>   that can be applied by Apple. Faster downloads and more space for
>   other apps and content provides a better user experience.

There should not be any performance impacts.

Answer (score 1):

- Starting with Xcode 14, bitcode is no longer required for watchOS and
  tvOS applications, and the App Store no longer accepts bitcode
  submissions from Xcode 14.
- Xcode no longer builds bitcode by default and generates a warning
  message if a project explicitly enables bitcode: “Building with
  bitcode is deprecated. Please update your project and/or target
  settings to disable bitcode.” The capability to build with bitcode
  will be removed in a future Xcode release. IPAs that contain bitcode
  will have the bitcode stripped before being submitted to the App
  Store. Debug symbols can only be downloaded from App Store Connect /
  TestFlight for existing bitcode submissions and are no longer
  available for submissions made with Xcode 14. (86118779)

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use the linked answer to circumvent the issue without any negative impact and without compromising a future AppStore submission?

yes

> What does the ENABLE_BITCODE actually do, will it be a non-optional requirement in the future?

`ENABLE_BITCODE` adds an intermediate representation of your code into binary. For watchOS, tvOS now it is mandatory

> Are there any performance impacts if I enable / disable it?

It has an impact on Xcode build and memory footprint when you *archive* your project

[[Bitcode]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66845532/4770877)