# Iphone 6 plus Simulator work OK Except for Device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, crash

I use Xcode 6.3.2 and Unity 5.1.1f1 on my mac mini. Unfortunately, I keep getting the following error message:"dyld`dyld_fatal_error" in XCode, if I try to run the app on the Iphone6 plus device, then app just crashed. The build is always succesful.

```
xcode 6.3 message:
**1**、dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
   -> 0x1200b9088 <+0>: brk  #0x3   Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=1, subcode=0x1200b9088)
```

**2、**

```
0 dyld_fatal_error
  1  dyld::halt(char const*)
  2  dyld::fastBindLazySymbol(ImageLoader*, unsigned long)
  3  dyld_stub_binder
  4  ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&)
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  11 _dyld_start
```

My Demo is very simple just content only have a cube,No various plugins!

Comment: did you set under Player Settings > Other Settings > Optimization the SDK Version to Device SDK? does it work on an other device? does it work with another unity version?

Answer (score 11):

Ok I had the same issue and I made it works by doing these things.

To solve "weird" issue like that, consider these step first :

- Clean and Build. (`Product` > `Clean` - `Product` > `Build`)
- Clean derived data. (`Windows` > `Projects` . (Select your project) > `delete`)

After these two steps, it still did not works for me so I switched `enable bitcode` off, following to a warning. So I made this :

- Switch `Enable Bitcode` to "off". in the `(YourAppName) Target` -> `Build Settings`.

[image: how to turn 'enable bitcode' off in xcode]

More information about `enable bitcode` are available [in this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31207170/4013333).

Answer (score 3):

Clean and Build.

> (Product > Clean - Product > Build)

Clean derived data.

> (Windows > Projects . (Select your project) > delete)

Worked for me.