# Xcode 7 and ENABLE_BITCODE=YES setting does not work

Tags: xcode7, bitcode

I have followed several threads around the new ENABLE_BITCODE setting in Xcode, have also tried as much as I can (admitted I'm not a xcode pro) but still cannot get the project to compile for use on my test phone?

My app runs fine on the simulator but I cannot deploy it onto my iPhone for testing. On latter one I just installed iOS 9 beta.

Now, here is the error message I receive. It appears the setting does not impact the PARSE.com lib, that is part of my project? **How can I get my project to deploy onto my phone?** Thanks for any advice.

```
    Ld /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/graffiti-  bnmizxueojwiqcbbnsvilljhosrw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods/Parse.framework/Parse normal armv7
cd /Users/xxxxxx/Documents/DigitalTempusDev/graffiti/Pods
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk -L/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/graffiti-bnmizxueojwiqcbbnsvilljhosrw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods -L/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/DigitalTempusDev/graffiti/Pods/Parse -F/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/graffiti-bnmizxueojwiqcbbnsvilljhosrw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods -filelist /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/graffiti-bnmizxueojwiqcbbnsvilljhosrw/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pods-Parse.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Parse.LinkFileList -install_name @rpath/Parse.framework/Parse -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -fembed-bitcode-marker -ObjC -lParseLib -lz -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework Social -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework AudioToolbox -framework Bolts -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework Foundation -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -single_module -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/graffiti-bnmizxueojwiqcbbnsvilljhosrw/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pods-Parse.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Parse_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/graffiti-bnmizxueojwiqcbbnsvilljhosrw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods/Parse.framework/Parse

---
ld: warning: -weak_framework is treated as -framework when used with -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES). Weak linking may still happen based on availability mark-up in headers
ld: warning: -weak_framework is treated as -framework when used with -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES). Weak linking may still happen based on availability mark-up in headers
ld: '/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/DigitalTempusDev/graffiti/Pods/Parse/libParseLib.a(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Are you sure you've selected `Enable Bitcode` to `NO` against build config you're using (eg `DEBUG`)? You can check it out in project->target->build settings-> search `enable bitcode`->set `NO` in DEBUG (good to remember to try to update libs before test release, maybe it'll contain bitcode already). Then `Edit Scheme` -> `Run` -> check if you have `DEBUG` config atm.

Comment: WELL! yes and no. I did not set it on the POD targets, that was my overlook. Your hint got me there. Thanks

Comment: Great to hear it :) will post it as an answer as it may be useful for other people.

Comment: Why we need to change Bitcode? Previously we not need to update its value. Any logical reason? Thanks

Comment: Did it all but still the app crash on the device with the same error. I am using iOS 9.1. Please help!

Answer (score 135):

Are you sure you've selected `Enable Bitcode` to `NO` against build config you're using (eg `DEBUG`)? You can check it out in project->target->build settings-> search `enable bitcode`->set `NO` in `DEBUG` (good to remember to try to update libs before test release, maybe it'll contain bitcode already). Then Edit Scheme -> Run -> check if you have `DEBUG` config atm.

[image]

Comment: @Zorayr As you've added image to my post: you should firstly check your app build settings and change this flag in app build settings. Only if it doesn't help, then do the same with Pods.

Comment: Will the application be accepted in the App store if the `Enable Bitcode` is set to `NO` ?

Comment: @NeAS Yes. Currently, there is no requirement to enable bitcode.

Answer (score 55):

Note that for projects using CocoaPods you should set `ENABLE_BITCODE = NO` on both the project and the Pods container project targets.

This error

```
Ld /Users/maximveksler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParseUI-gwtgmlgbpobjfjfjgkiwdahqveos/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ParseTwitterUtils.framework/ParseTwitterUtils normal arm64
    cd /Users/maximveksler/Developer/ParseUI-iOS/Pods
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk -L/Users/maximveksler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParseUI-gwtgmlgbpobjfjfjgkiwdahqveos/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/maximveksler/Developer/ParseUI-iOS/Pods/ParseTwitterUtils -F/Users/maximveksler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParseUI-gwtgmlgbpobjfjfjgkiwdahqveos/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/maximveksler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParseUI-gwtgmlgbpobjfjfjgkiwdahqveos/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/ParseTwitterUtils.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ParseTwitterUtils.LinkFileList -install_name @rpath/ParseTwitterUtils.framework/ParseTwitterUtils -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -dead_strip -fembed-bitcode-marker -ObjC -lParseTwitterUtilsLib -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework Social -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework AudioToolbox -framework Bolts -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework Foundation -framework Parse -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -single_module -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1.8.1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/maximveksler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParseUI-gwtgmlgbpobjfjfjgkiwdahqveos/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/ParseTwitterUtils.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ParseTwitterUtils_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/maximveksler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParseUI-gwtgmlgbpobjfjfjgkiwdahqveos/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ParseTwitterUtils.framework/ParseTwitterUtils

ld: '/Users/maximveksler/Developer/ParseUI-iOS/Pods/ParseTwitterUtils/libParseTwitterUtilsLib.a(PFTwitterAuthenticationProvider.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

was resolved by:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does Apple reject app if we submit it with option Enable Bitcode = NO?

Comment: @G.Ganesh please post as a separate question. The policy varies between tvOS and watchOS where the answer is YES. iOS the answer is currently no, future YES.

Comment: @GaneshGuturi Currently yes, but probably Apple will cut it at some point in the future. More explanation eg here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31207170/849616.

Answer (score 17):

I had also faced the same problem in Xcode7. Solution for this:

- go to `PROJECT`
- build `Settings`
- select `All Tab`
- type in search `Enable Bitcode`
- `Update Flag` to `No` (which will be beneath of your project (second column))

Answer (score 16):

I had similar problem with GoogleAnalytics cocoa pod library, and the library was not compiling for iPhone 6 with iOS 8.

My solution was to turn to NO "Enable Bitcode" flag in target of the application project - not in Pods project.

Comment: That's what I've said in the comment to my answer. To try to do it on project settings, if and only if that's not working then switch to pod project.

Comment: Switching the target and the project to build settings bitcode NO does not work for ARCHIVING.  Does work find for Sim builds.  XCODE 7.0.1

Answer (score 11):

If your Bitcode is not showing please selec All. When xcode select Basic your Bitcode option is not showing.

[image]

When you select All you can see Bitcode. After then set No for ads config
[image]

Answer (score 10):

I just set it for my project.

MyProjectTarget -> Build Settings -> Enable Bitcode = NO

Comment: Will the application be rejected in the App store?

Answer (score 5):

As everybody said, the answer is **set `Enable Bitcode` to `No` in build settings**, but I think some of you might be interested in doing this from the **command line**.

My Xcode project is being generated by Unity and I don't want any manual intervention on the Xcode project settings. Maybe there's a better way or a tool that can edit Build Settings a bit like how [PlistBuddy](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/PlistBuddy.8.html) lets you update values in `plist` files. I don't know any tool that does this for build settings so I'm using [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed).

> sed: Run replacements based on regular expressions.

### How to set `Enable Bitcode` to `No` from command line:

Here, my project name is `Unity-iPhone` so I run the following command from the root of my Xcode project:

```sh
sed -i -e 's/ENABLE_BITCODE = YES;/ENABLE_BITCODE = NO;/g' \ 
Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

> -e      -- specify sed commands to run
>   -i      -- edit files in-place, running scripts separately for each file

Remove `-i` if you only want a preview of what it does ;)

Note that *all* of your build configurations will be changed using this command, the line `ENABLE_BITCODE = YES;` appeared 6 times in my `project.pbxproj`.

Now my build steps can be fully automated as [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) takes care of the rest!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't find enable_bitcode flag. Click "All" tab on the upper toolbar beside the search bar.
[image]

Comment: Please add some code to better explain your answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this command in terminal if you arn't able to change BITCODE settings withing the project,

xcodebuild -target "target" -configuration "configuration"  ENABLE_BITCODE=NO

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Cocoapods, this will solve the problem:

```rb
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```