# Unity Xcode build linker error

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, linker-errors, bitcode

We are trying to build a Unity game in Xcode but keep getting this error:

> ld:
>   '/Users/Pero/Documents/GitHub/MyGame/XCodeProject/Pods/GooglePlayGames/gpg-cpp-sdk/ios/gpg.framework/gpg(libgpg.a-armv7-master.o)'
>   does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled
>   (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the
>   vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

We are using:

- Unity 5.1.1f1
- Xcode Version 7.1 (7B91b)

We have these frameworks included in the Xcode project:

- gpg.framework
- GooglePlus.framework
- GoogleOpenSource.framework
- GoogleMobileAds.framework
- CoreText.framework
- AdSupport.framework
- AudioToolBox.framework
- AVFoundation.framework
- CFNetwork.framework
- CoreGraphics.framework
- CoreLocation.framework
- CoreMedia.framework
- CoreMotion.framework
- CoreVideo.framework
- Foundation.framework
- iAd.framework
- MediaPlayer.framework
- OpenAL.framework
- OpenGLES.framework
- QuartzCore.framework
- SystemConfiguration.framework
- UIKit.framework
- StoreKit.framework
- CoreTelephony.framework

We also have Cocoapods installed and this is in our Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'GooglePlayGames'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
```

We have tried searching the issue, and none of the solutions we found worked. We have tried enabling and disabling the bitcode, Build Active Architecture Only, setting or deleting Search Paths... Here are some links:

[xcode-5-1-missing-required-architecture-arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22331908/xcode-5-1-missing-required-architecture-arm64)

[new-warnings-in-ios9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848208/new-warnings-in-ios9)

[impact-of-xcode-build-options-enable-bitcode-yes-no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088618/impact-of-xcode-build-options-enable-bitcode-yes-no)

[error-after-updating-to-xcode-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32636622/error-after-updating-to-xcode-7)

[xcode-7-and-enable-bitcode-yes-setting-does-not-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31561286/xcode-7-and-enable-bitcode-yes-setting-does-not-work)

[apple-llvm-6-0-error-clang-failed-with-exit-code-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26772504/apple-llvm-6-0-error-clang-failed-with-exit-code-1)

It is our first time using Xcode. We have built the Android version from Unity with no problems.

There was also a problem with creating the Xcode project from Unity on a Mac (Unity kept crashing), so the Xcode project was created on a PC.

Comment: tried with disable bitcode?

Comment: ... "We have tried enabling and disabling the bitcode, Build Active Architecture Only, setting or deleting Search Paths"

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest Unity?

Comment: @user3071284 We can try to upgrade Unity, but this is an older project that is built for Android and only recently we decided to build an iOS version so we are afraid that something could go wrong with existing Unity functionality. Do you really think that latest Unity can fix this issue?

Comment: Unity is currently on 5.2.2, so a good bit has changed with IL2CPP and iOS-related things. You can always file a bug report with Unity, search through their public issue tracker, or downgrade back to 5.1.1 if you keep a backup of your project as it is now.

Comment: We updated Unity to 5.2.2 on a different machine and this enabled the Xcode project export on a Mac machine and fixed the `bitcode` error. But there are some new errors that I'll post in a new thread if we'll be unable to solve them. Post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as answer.

Comment: Building on Unity 5.5 I'm facing this problem as well. Did you do anything else besides updating Unity, to fix that error? I'm on a newer release already.

Comment: No I did nothing else beside updating Unity. But this was for version 5.2.2 and since version 5.3 we stopped with iOS development so I don't know what is the status for version 5.5