# Black Stripe is displayed in View in Old Projects

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios9, xcode-project

When I try to run some old projects I get a **black stripe** as image below.

I tried to change the `SDK version` in `Deployment Target` and also tried update the `XIB` file.

I am using `iPhone 6s iOS 9.1`

What should I do?

[image: black stripe]

For instance,

This old project has the **Black Stripe**: [Myo SDK with a sample](https://s3.amazonaws.com/thalmicdownloads/ios/Myo-iOS-SDK-0.5.2.zip)

In this project is necessary to set [Bitcode to NO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31563941/4850561).

Comment: i think you have add Launch Screen in the projects like this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701553/launch-screen-that-behaves-exactly-like-launch-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add Default-568h@2x.png file with resolution 640x1136.

I then updated the 'App Icons and Launch Images' Section to look like this:

[image]

Tested on Xcode 7 with all devices on Simulator with iOS 9 and it worked!!

Answer (score 3):

Earlier the Screen size of iPhones were limited to iPhone 4S.

So either integrate Launch images for following screen sizes

- for 3.5 inch Devices
- for 4 inch Devices
- for 4.7 inch Devices
- for 5.5 inch Devices

or Launch Screen XIB for all devices.