# Xcode 7 linker issue with Google Maps SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, xcode7-beta4

I just downloaded Xcode 7 beta 4 and am trying to build my Swift 2.0 application but I am getting the following error which I can't figure out the solution to:

> ld: warning: -weak_framework is treated as -framework when used with
>   -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES). Weak linking may still happen based on availability mark-up in headers ld:
>   'path/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps(GMSBillingPointRecorder.o)'
>   does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled
>   (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the
>   vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: What version of GoogleMaps framework are you using?

Comment: I installed it using cocoa pod and it says it installed google maps 1.10.1

Comment: It strange, I created new project in Xcode 7 beta 4, and installed google maps 1.10.1 by cocoa pods. Everything works fine. I will advice to you to create new project and migrate your source files from current project. Also try to change value of ENABLE_BITCODE flag in your project settings. In my case it works with any value (true, false) of this flag.

Comment: Alright I'll try that and get back to you.....thank you for the suggestion

Comment: I updated comment, before creating new project, try to change value of ENABLE_BITCODE flag.

Comment: I'm a noob here with the new Xcode how would I go about it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I changed the ENABLE_BITCODE Flag to No and compiled properly thanks @Visput for the answer

Comment: Isn't ENABLE_BITCODE mandatory for app store deployments? I'm BTW having the same issue with it GMSBillingPointRecorder.o does not contain bitcode

Comment: @decades: not for iOS

Answer (score 21):

Setting **ENABLE_BITCODE** flag to **NO** solves the issue.

For those wondering if its safe to disable it. **Yes it is.**

As per Apple Doc

> **Bitcode (iOS, watchOS)**
>
> Bitcode is an intermediate representation of a compiled program. Apps
>   you upload to iTunes Connect that contain bitcode will be compiled and
>   linked on the App Store. Including bitcode will allow Apple to
>   re-optimize your app binary in the future without the need to submit a
>   new version of your app to the store.
>
> Xcode hides symbols generated during build time by default, so they
>   are not readable by Apple. Only if you choose to include symbols when
>   uploading your app to iTunes Connect would the symbols be sent to
>   Apple. You must include symbols to receive crash reports from Apple.
>
> **Note: For iOS apps, bitcode is the default, but optional. If you
>   provide bitcode, all apps and frameworks in the app bundle need to
>   include bitcode. For watchOS apps, bitcode is required.**

Bitcode is part of Apple's new effort for App thinning. At the time of this writing, it is optional but could potentially be required later on. I think Apple is giving the frameworks/libs communities time to adapt.

Edit:
In Xcode 7 you upload your app to iTunes connect in an intermediate state called **Bitcode**. When users download your app, the App Store will automatically produce an optimized version of your app (i.e., 64-bit if needed) to match the device the user is using.

For now what we can do is to disable bitcode and wait for Google Maps SDK's update.

**UPDATE**

SDK 1.11.0 - now supports Bitcode

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/releases?hl=en

Resources:

[Impact of Xcode build options "Enable bitcode" Yes/No](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088618/impact-of-xcode-build-options-enable-bitcode-yes-no)

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/ios9

Comment: The issue for GoogleMaps api is tracked here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8219 , vote for it if you need it.

Answer (score 5):

Just to be clear where to disable bitcode:
Target -> Build Settings -> Enable Bitcode -> No

[image: Disable Bitcode]

GIF image is courtesy of @stevechen

Answer (score 0):

Google has resolved this issue in SDK Version 1.11.0 - December 2015. See the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/releases):

Bitcode is now included in the SDK binary for all device architectures. ([Issue 8219](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8219)).