# XCode7 position independent code in the linker.

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, llvm, llvm-clang

I have upgraded to XCode 7 and I am getting an error while linking

> ld: -no_pie and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES)
>   cannot be used together

I changed the xcode setting to generate position dependent code but the linking still fails. The -no_pie still appears in the linker's output. How can I disable the -no_pie?

[image]

Comment: in buildsettings, set bitcode to NO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find the `enable bitcode` build settings and set to `NO`:

[image: Build settings]

Comment: Is this safe? Is this added with iOS9/XCode7?

Comment: yes my friend, For iOS apps, bitcode is the default, but optional. If you provide bitcode, all apps and frameworks in the app bundle need to include bitcode. For watchOS apps, bitcode is required.

Comment: see this link may be helps with you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088618/impact-of-xcode-build-options-enable-bitcode-yes-no

Comment: Thanks Anbu, I will change the settings.