# How to fix Facebook SDK "does not contain bitcode" error?

Tags: ios, facebook, swift2, xcode7, bitcode

I got below error after updating my Xcode to the latest version:

> ld: '/Users/mimicreative/Documents/Kerja/Backup/FacebookSDK/FBSDKMessengerShareKit.framework/FBSDKMessengerShareKit(FBSDKMessengerApplicationStateManager.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7

However I don't got this error on the earlier version of Xcode. And that error happened when I archive my project.

Comment: update your Facebook SDK v 4.6 other wise change setting in .plist file Enable BitCode = No;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there is already an update for facebook where bitcode is enabled. check in cocoapods and you eill find it. its Version 4.5 i think

This is used for appthining.
If you dont want to update the sdk you cam turn off bitcode in your project.
Go to your target-> Settings and serch for bitcode. Than turn the option to NO. By default its activated

**EDIT:**
Facebook Version is 4.6 as @Dharmesh Dhorajiya said :)

Comment: Great that i could help you: Wish a nice day ;)

Comment: Oh, now i see that you wasnt the question writer .. hehe. thx man :)

Comment: I did update Facebook SDK to version 4.36.0 (last version) and it worked fine without having to disable bitcode.

Answer (score 5):

find `enable bitcode` build settings and set to `NO`:

[image: Build settings]

or else upgrade your FacebookSDK

Comment: iOS 9 and xcode 7 onwards bitcode concept is introduced, If you provide bitcode, all apps and frameworks in the app bundle need to include bitcode. For watchOS apps, bitcode is required. for future purpose it introduced, at the same time in a single Ripa file can execute in multiple mobile platforms for future purpose it added , additional information related to bit code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088618/impact-of-xcode-build-options-enable-bitcode-yes-no

Comment: correct, Appthining was still buggy in xcode 7 and they fixed it in Xcode 7.0.1 if iam not wrong