# ENABLE_BITCODE in xcode 7 should provide all image sizes for XCode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I am using some images with only 1x and use it for all sizes and some images are only 2x ,

Now by enabling the bitcode flag in Xcode should regenerate all images with three sizes?

also the splash screens and icons should i added it to the image asset catalogs  or the keep it on the project as files does this affect the app size?

Comment: Just to make things clear: you're talking about slicing, bitcode has nothing to do with different assets. More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html. It says there: 'You must use the asset catalog in order for resources to be sliced.' Do you use asset catalogs?

Comment: yes but i did not add all image sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `Bitcode` is a total different concept which generates intermediate representation of a compiled program. This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088618/impact-of-xcode-build-options-enable-bitcode-yes-no) beautifully explains about it.

I believe you are looking for `Slicing`. Per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html):

> Slicing is the process of creating and delivering variants of the app
>   bundle for different target devices. A variant contains only the
>   executable architecture and resources that are needed for the target
>   device. You continue to develop and upload full versions of your app
>   to iTunes Connect. The App Store will create and deliver different
>   variants based on the devices your app supports. Image resources are
>   sliced according to their resolution and device family. GPU resources
>   are sliced according to device capabilities. When the user installs an
>   app, a variant for the user’s device is downloaded and installed.

Trusting you are talking about `Slicing`:

> In Xcode, specify target devices and provide multiple resolutions of
>   images in the asset catalog.

So you should provide all target device images in asset catalog for slicing to work effectively.