# Disabling Bitcode option from project will disable app thinning feature from app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I see many posts describing App Thinning and enabling and disabling Bitcode from project settings.

I also followed detailed explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/a/31207170/5570570.

But, what I want to understand is disabling Bitcode will disable full App Thinning concept? **Can't I have access to On Demand Resources feature even though Bitcode is disabled**?

I also understand that Apple has not made Bitcode mandatory but in future they may plan to make it mandatory.

Let me know if I am misunderstanding anything about App Thinning?

Answer (score 0):

when you disable this feature then your app size remains same for every device.
When you enable it then for every device apple make a different binary.... suppose you have iphone 5s then only resources like images that are for iphone 5s will be installed to user that make .ipa smaller... means user will download only that resources that are for his device

Comment: I totally understand that, but my question is Can't I have access to On Demand Resources feature even though Bitcode is disabled?

Comment: yes you can use this feature even bitcode is disabled.. you can use tags to distinguish between different devices