# Enable bitcode Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios9, xcode7, bitcode, myo

I'm having this error in XCode 7.1 when building the application for iOS9: (...) MyoKit(TLMHub.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

When building the application for the simulation, it works.

I've been searching and I can't find an option to enable bitcode. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the source to MyoKit?

Comment: Just go to your project build settings and search for bitcode, and set it to YES

Comment: @Mr.T there isn't a bitcode option in build settings for Xcode 7.1, that's the problem that I have...

Comment: No, there is build option available for Xcode 7.1. May be you are looking at wrong place.

Comment: @Mr.T can you tell me where it is, please? I've been searching in different places and I couldn't find it, and more people on Stackoverflow have the same problem. Thank you!

Comment: You can find more info here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088618/impact-of-xcode-build-options-enable-bitcode-yes-no

Answer (score 2):

In project Navigator, select your project:

[image]

And then Select your project,click on build settings, and search for bitcode,and set BitCode to YES.

[image]

**Make sure you click on All option instead of Basic.**

Comment: Don't you want to set it to "no" if there are 3rd-party libraries that don't have it enabled?

Comment: I will set it to NO for my project targets, if it isnt needed. Is there any other place do I need to taken care of @trojanfoe

Comment: that was the problem. You need All option selected. Thank you very much! I tried to upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation. Thx!

Comment: @Mr.T I don't think so, no.  The real issue, of course, is if you use one 3rd-party library with it enabled. and another with it disabled.  Then you are stuck until you can get hold of compatible versions.  Apple do love to make our lives difficult...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `MyoKit` is not compiled with Bitcode enabled. Unfortunately until that SDK supports Bitcode, you'll have to disable it for your project.