# Is there an alternative to opencore amr to convert wav to amr on iOS?

Tags: ios, audio, bitcode, amr

I have a project that needs to send amr files to the server.
The only solution I found so far is a cocoapods library, a swift one, linked to different builds of opencore-amr library.

https://github.com/feuvan/opencore-amr-iOS

cocoapods: https://cocoapods.org/pods/TSVoiceConverter

Right now, I can compile in arm7, arm7s, arm64. That's ok.
But what I would like is a project totally convertible to bitcode.

[Impact of Xcode build options "Enable bitcode" Yes/No](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088618/impact-of-xcode-build-options-enable-bitcode-yes-no)

I see 2 solutions so far:

- find or build a pure swift Wav to AMR converter.
- change the file format on the server and use iOS native formats.

Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a pull request and it was merged a few weeks back. So latest version of this library now supports bitcode

Comment: oh my god, that's really really nice Deny! Thanks!! https://github.com/hilen/TSVoiceConverter/commit/c4e70e29b7dd30d70fda586e1abfaba29716d1bd

Comment: I tested version 0.1.2 and it works. Thanks again Deny.