# "libParseLib.a does not contain bitcode" error

Tags: ios, cocoapods, parse-server, bitcode

I never had any problems when using CocoaPods up to this point (I used it a few times to integrate Parse into my iOS app). But this time I am puzzled by the message below.

When I previously used CocoaPods the project was containing only one target, this time it contains several. There may be something to be careful about, in such a case, that I don't know of. Anyway, here is the message I am getting:

```
        ld: '..../MyApp/Pods/Parse/libParseLib.a(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)' does not contain bitcode.
    You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE),
    obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target.
for architecture arm64
        clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried to change the Enable Bitcode flag at various level, but whatever I do I keep getting the same error.

Has anyone had this kind of issue? Or knows what to do about it?

Note that this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088618/impact-of-xcode-build-options-enable-bitcode-yes-no) is related to my question but it unfortunately does not provide me a useful answer.

Update: I add hereafter the full text I get in the logs under Xcode, in case it may help someone to see where the problem is:

```
Ld /Users/georgewhashington/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxizsrrgeilklkhdylflpsafjrd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Parse-framework/Parse.framework/Parse normal arm64
    cd /Users/georgewhashington/Documents/iOS/MyApp/Pods
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.2.sdk -L/Users/georgewhashington/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxizsrrgeilklkhdylflpsafjrd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Parse-framework -L/Users/georgewhashington/Documents/iOS/MyApp/Pods/Parse -F/Users/georgewhashington/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxizsrrgeilklkhdylflpsafjrd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Parse-framework -F/Users/georgewhashington/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxizsrrgeilklkhdylflpsafjrd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Bolts-framework -filelist /Users/georgewhashington/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxizsrrgeilklkhdylflpsafjrd/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/Parse-framework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Parse.LinkFileList -install_name @rpath/Parse.framework/Parse -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/georgewhashington/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxizsrrgeilklkhdylflpsafjrd/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/Parse-framework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Parse_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fembed-bitcode-marker -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lParseLib -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework Social -framework AudioToolbox -framework Bolts -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework Foundation -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -single_module -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/georgewhashington/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxizsrrgeilklkhdylflpsafjrd/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/Parse-framework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Parse_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/georgewhashington/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxizsrrgeilklkhdylflpsafjrd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Parse-framework/Parse.framework/Parse

ld: '..../MyApp/Pods/Parse/libParseLib.a(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Impact of Xcode build options "Enable bitcode" Yes/No](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088618/impact-of-xcode-build-options-enable-bitcode-yes-no)

Comment: As mentioned in the above question, this was previously a warning which was to be changed to an error in the future. Disabling the 'Enable bitcode' setting should allow you to build successfully.

Comment: As I wrote I tried several settings and setting 'Enable bitcode' to NO didn't make any difference.

Comment: The link given as a possible duplicate is certainly related but it doesn't give me an answer.

Comment: That's odd, have you tried cleaning (⇧⌘K) the project after disabling bitcode?

Comment: Since you mentioned you have several targets in the workspace, did you double check that you changed the setting on the correct target?

Comment: Yes to both questions. Unless I am not disabling in the right place, but I know only one.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce with the same lib linked through Cocoapods.

Comment: I had a similar issue, not so long ago, without using cocoapod. And using cocoapod got me out of trouble (I don't quite know why). Now the problem is back. It was on a different project though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134097/discussion-between-michel-and-xoudini).

Answer (score 9):

My solution was to disable bitcode in the project, like this

[image]

everything works fine after.