# Introduced homemade framework in xcode , compile bitcode error of the archive?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, archive

I want to Introduce `Homemade framework` in Xcode. When I uploaded after archiving , I encountered compile bitcode error ...

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Uncheck rebuild from bitcode option while archiving & check once if it is working.

Comment: I changed Enable Bitcode to No ,It's working !! ,thank you very much!

Comment: ok you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please  Uncheck rebuild from bitcode option while archiving build.

For information visit [Impact of Xcode build options "Enable bitcode" Yes/No](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088618/impact-of-xcode-build-options-enable-bitcode-yes-no)