# What is the include bitcode option for in XCode while creating a build?

Tags: swift3

While creating an .ipa file using XCode, I am seeing this option of include  bitcode or not. Please check the attached image below

[image]

Should I check this option or not ? Which is better ?

Comment: Opinion based: check it. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html

Comment: check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088618/impact-of-xcode-build-options-enable-bitcode-yes-no