# Creating iOS Framework for device and Universal configuration with bitcode enable and bitcode disable from Command Line terminal

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bitcode, ios-universal-framework

```
#!/bin/sh

UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

# make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
    -configuration  ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  \
    BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} \
    -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" \
    BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build

# Step 2. Copy the framework structure (from iphoneos build) to the universal folder
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"


# Step 4. Create universal binary file using lipo and place the combined executable in the copied framework directory
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" \
    "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" \ 
    "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"

# Step 5. Convenience step to copy the framework to the project's directory
cp -R "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${PROJECT_DIR}"

# Step 6. Convenience step to open the project's directory in Finder
open "${PROJECT_DIR}"
```

**I have above shell script to create framework for device and universal from Xcode build options.**

**Is is possible to create/Generate iOS Framework from Command terminal with above shell script with below configuration???**

- 1) Create framework for device bitcode disable
- 2) Create framework for device bitcode enable
- 3) Create framework for Universal bitcode disable
- 4) Create framework for Universal bitcode enable

> Please let me know the steps to create/generate iOS Framework from
>   command terminal. Must appreciate for the best explanation

Comment: Can you check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_SQ8zw0Sq0 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088618/impact-of-xcode-build-options-enable-bitcode-yes-no

Comment: For **2020**, you can check this repo https://github.com/gurhub/surmagic. Best

Answer (score 3):

Just add the argument to your `xcodebuild`

`ENABLE_BITCODE=NO` for  disabling bitcode

`ENABLE_BITCODE=YES` for enabling bitcode

For example

```
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build ENABLE_BITCODE=NO
```

Comment: @hariszaman....can u explain clearly from my question and explain what are the command i can use to generate framework with bitcode enable and disable from command terminal...it should be help full to all...

Comment: @Priya He did! See the code at the end. This is your code (he copied your code from the script) modified so that bitcode is not built. Replace the last NO with YES and bitcode is built. This is exactly the answer to your question.

Comment: @Mecki....from terminal how can i create framework...what are steps i have to use to create from terminal

Comment: @hariszaman....How can i create each framework separately with Below configuration

1) Create framework for device bitcode disable 
2) Create framework for device bitcode enable
3) Create framework for Universal bitcode disable
4) Create framework for Universal bitcode enable

Using Terminal how can i create framework. Please let me know the steps and commands i have use to create framework from terminal

Comment: @Priya you need to write a bash script and then add it to Target > New Run Phase script. And example of it is just above you posted :)

Comment: Just set ENABLE_BITCODE=YES or ENABLE_BITCODE=NO as @hariszaman said

Answer (score 1):

In the shell script you posted, replace the code under `# Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions` with the following appropriately.

1) Create framework for device bitcode disable:

```
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
-configuration  ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  \
BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build ENABLE_BITCODE=NO
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} \
-sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" \
BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build ENABLE_BITCODE=YES
```

2) Create framework for device bitcode enable

```
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
-configuration  ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  \
BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build ENABLE_BITCODE=YES
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} \
-sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" \
BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build ENABLE_BITCODE=YES
```

3) Create framework for Universal bitcode disable

```
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
-configuration  ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  \
BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build ENABLE_BITCODE=NO
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} \
-sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" \
BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build ENABLE_BITCODE=NO
```

4) Create framework for Universal bitcode enable

```
 xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
-configuration  ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  \
BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build ENABLE_BITCODE=YES
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} \
-sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" \
BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build ENABLE_BITCODE=YES
```

EDIT:
To build the framework, you can do either of the below:
1. Replacing the code for each config, go to terminal and run the shell script by navigating to the folder containing the shell script and running `./<nameOfTheShellScriptFile>.sh`. But make sure you have the build settings available there. That will create the framework with the appropriate configuration in the directory `${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal`.
2. Add a run script in the Xcode. Open your project in Xcode, click on the schemes dropdown (beside Stop button) and choose your framework scheme. Open the dropdown again and click on "Edit Scheme...". You see 6 actions to the left. You choose which action makes more sense to add the script to (do you want to create this universal framework on every Run action or only when you archive?). Drop down that action and click on Post-actions. Click on + button to add a new action and click on "New Run Script Action". Set the "Provide build settings from" to your framework target to get the appropriate build settings. Paste the script in the text area and click close. Now after every time you perform the action you put the script under, the script runs and builds the framework again for both device and simulator architectures and puts the universal framework in your project directory. It takes some time for this to complete especially if your project is big so wait patiently until the finder opens up to reveal your project directory containing the framework. Now you can either change the code in the script every time you want a different config (bitcode enabled or disabled), or add different schemes for different config and follow this whole step for each of the schemes with appropriate script.

Comment: ....Thanks for your rly...Can u explain the steps what are the changes i have to do in xcode framework source,Build Setting, Run Script and Terminal what are the commands required to generate framework...

Comment: @SanthoshR...Please let me know Any Script should i add in Xcode runscript or from the terminal i have to use the above shell script for each framework generation???

Comment: @Priya Click on the current scheme (usually the app/framework name beside the stop button), in the options, choose 'New Scheme'.

Comment: @Priya If my answer works for you, please accept it as the right answer.