# What are the differences between 'Enable Bitcode' and 'Rebuild from Bitcode'?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone, xcode

- When to use 'Enable Bitcode' ?
- When to use 'Rebuild from Bitcode' ?
- What are the advantages over ?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this link [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31088744/10460820)

**Bitcode**

> Bitcode is an intermediate representation of a compiled program. Apps you upload to iTunes Connect that contain bitcode will be compiled and linked on the App Store. Including bitcode will allow Apple to re-optimize your app binary in the future without the need to submit a new version of your app to the store.
>
> **Note**: For iOS apps, bitcode is the default, but optional. If you provide bitcode, all apps and frameworks in the app bundle need to include bitcode. For watchOS apps, bitcode is required

So you should disabled bitcode until all the frameworks of your app have bitcode enabled.

And might be any of the framework of the Project have bitcode enabled that's why it's asking for Rebuild from Bitcode.