# Compressing files to to make iOS app smaller

Tags: ios, compression, image-compression

I recently completed a game that I uploaded to iTunes connect. It's currently in the app store but is a whopping 264mb. I didn't even realize how big it was until trying to download it on a device. I take it this is too large to be a successful app but there really weren't any more pictures than any other normal iOS game app, probably less.

If I want to go about compressing them, what's the easiest way? Should I upload them one by one to Gimp or something of the sort or is there some sort of automatic file compressor for iOS apps? I know it's out on a limb but obviously would save a lot of time.

Also, once that's done where can I check the size of the app?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tools like ImageOptim to batch compress all your images without loosing quality: https://imageoptim.com

For estimating the App Store size, check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30620479/1983667

Comment: Cool thanks! Do you think 264mb is outrageously large for an iOS app though? I'm having second thoughts as I've heard there are some games that big. If that's acceptable I think I'll save myself the effort and start advertising.

Comment: It is definitely a lot. Keep in mind that the cellular app download limit is currently 100MB, so users are only able to download your app when connected to a WiFi: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=02122015a

You can also have a look at On-Demand Resources, a new feature of iOS 9 that allows to download resources like images, files, ecc when they are needed instead of all-at-one when downloading the app from the store: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/

Comment: So I just realized that my app is the size it is because of the sound files and not the images. I suppose those are much harder to compress, any insight on that? Thanks.

Comment: Compressing (png) images in advance is of no use, because xcode recompresses them anyway, more info on this you can find here: https://bjango.com/articles/pngcompression/