# "TestFlight variants differ from store variants and have smaller sizes." Why?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

In iTunes Connect, under Activity -> All Builds -> *latest build* -> App Store File Sizes, I see this message:

> TestFlight variants differ from store variants and have smaller sizes.

Why is that the case? What is left out? How representative are the displayed sizes? If the smaller variant works perfectly well in TestFlight, why does Apple distribute a bigger variant in the store?

I could easily imagine TestFlight variants being *bigger* (less optimization/trimming being done), but smaller seems weird. The [guide on App Thinning](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html) does not enlighten.

Comment: Hi, you have a suitable answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620322/estimated-apps-store-size (read the update section in the end of the answer).

Comment: So you're saying TestFlight builds are not encrypted, and thus compress better, than App Store builds? If that is the case, I wonder why Apple wouldn't choose to encrypt them _after_ compressing them...