# App size in ios is too large for google maps sdk for ios

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios

*I am using google maps sdk for my app in ios, the size of my exported .ipa file is 111 mb is it normal or not?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increase in app size after use of Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507408/increase-in-app-size-after-use-of-google-maps-sdk-for-ios)

Comment: Given the amount of time that has passed since the possible duplicate question was asked and answered, new info could be useful here! @makkhokher, did you get an answer to your question?